# Rails update one to one and one to many - create child object if not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have three models: `Employee`, `User`, and `Role`. Relationship between these classes are `employee` --- one_to_one -- `user` and `user` -- one_to_many -- `role`.

My create action is working fine with following strong params methods

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :email, user_attributes: [:id, role_ids:[]])
end
```

For update if employee record has no user object, I am instantiating new user, mapping it to employee and calling update by passing string params. However, the update is failing with message:

> Failed to save the new associated user

My update method code is

```
def update
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  if params[:employee][:user_attributes] != nil && params[:employee][:user_attributes][:role_ids] != nil && ! params[:employee][:user_attributes][:role_ids].empty?
    if @employee.user == nil
      @employee.user = User.new
      temp_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
      @employee.user.is_temp_password = true
      @employee.user.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
      @employee.user.email = @employee.email
      @employee.user.email = params[:employee][:email] if  params[:employee][:email]
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @employee.update(employee_params)
      format.json { render json: @employee.as_json}
    else
      format.json {render :json => @employee.errors.as_json, :status => 422}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesnt look like you are saving the new user record to me.

Comment: probably after instantiating the new user, you should also save it by calling @employee.user.save

Comment: ok. i want update and save happen in same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think as the above users suggested, you need to save the new User Object but also I think you should have the User creation code inside of the Employee create since you you would need to auto create it anyways in the update

Not sure if you also aware of helpers blank?, present? but I rewrote your code with that

```
def update
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  if params[:employee][:user_attributes].present? && params[:employee][:user_attributes][:role_ids].present? && params[:employee][:user_attributes][:role_ids].present?    
    unless @employee.user
      user = User.new
      @employee.user = user
      temp_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
      user.is_temp_password = true
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
      user.email = @employee.email
      user.email = params[:employee][:email] if  params[:employee][:email]
      user.save!
    end
  end
```